# Splitting a string representation of a nested list into string representations of the sublists

Tags: python, regex, split

I have the following:

```
str = '[5.955894, 45.817792], [10.49238, 45.817792], [10.49238, 47.808381], [5.955894, 47.808381]'
```

I want to split it so that I have an array of strings like

`['[5.955894, 45.817792]', '[10.49238, 45.817792]', ...]`

So that the `[...]` objects are elements of the array. It is important that the enclosing `[` and `]` are included. I've come so far:

```
re.split('\D,\s\D', str)
```

But that gives me:

```
['[5.955894, 45.817792', '10.49238, 45.817792', '10.49238, 47.808381', '5.955894, 47.808381]']
```

Comment: `eval('[' + str + ']')` if it comes from trusted source.

Comment: What do you want to achieve ultimately?

Comment: Second line of code in my question. That's what I want.

Comment: @nhahtdh -- that `eval` won't give what OP wants, but as a side note, there is `ast.literal_eval` which would do the same thing as `eval` without the security implications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I prefer to use `re.findall` and specify what I *want* instead of trying to describe the delimiter for `re.split`

```
>>> s = '[5.955894, 45.817792], [10.49238, 45.817792], [10.49238, 47.808381], [5.955894, 47.808381]'
>>> re.findall(r"\[[^\]]*\]",s)
['[5.955894, 45.817792]', '[10.49238, 45.817792]', '[10.49238, 47.808381]', '[5.955894, 47.808381]']
```

1. `\[` matches [
2. `[^\]]*` matches anything but ]
3. `\]` matches ]

Comment: Alternatively, instead of the X-then-anything-but-Y-then-Y pattern you can use the non-greedy version: `r"\[.*?\]"`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `re.split` with *look-ahead*:

```
>>> s = '[5.955894, 45.817792], [10.49238, 45.817792], [10.49238, 47.808381], [5.955894, 47.808381]'

>>> re.split(",[ ]*(?=\[)", s)
['[5.955894, 45.817792]', '[10.49238, 45.817792]', '[10.49238, 47.808381]', '[5.955894, 47.808381]']
```

And don't use `str` as variable. It's shadows the built-in.

The below pattern:

```
,[ ]*(?=\[)
```

will match the `comma(,)` and some whitespaces, which is followed by a `[`

You can even do it with `look-behind`. So, `(?<=\]),[ ]*` will also work.

Comment: Why not just `r"(?<=\]),"`?

Comment: @mgilson. Yeah both of them are not actually required.

Comment: Although I do suppose that matching the whitespace around the comma is necessary to prevent it from appearing in the output -- Though I would typically fall back on `\s*` rather than `[ ]*` -- but it all depends on what you want to match I suppose.

Comment: @mgilson.. Well, if there can be any other kind of whitespaces like tabs, or newlines, rather than just `space`, then `\s` will be needed. But it's also depends upon OP, what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive procedure I've written, I think it solves your problem but couldn't be the best.

```
>>>def split_string(strg, begin = '[', end = ']'):  
    myList = []  
    string = ''  
    for char in strg:  
        if char == begin:  
            string = ''  
        string += char  
        if char == end:  
            myList.append(string)  
    return myList  
>>>strg = '[5.955894, 45.817792], [10.49238, 45.817792], [10.49238, 47.808381], [5.955894, 47.808381]'  
>>>split_string(strg)  
['[5.955894, 45.817792]', '[10.49238, 45.817792]', '[10.49238, 47.808381]', '[5.955894, 47.808381]']
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @nhahtdh comment.

Depends on your trust issues.

```
In [510]: txt = '[5.955894, 45.817792], [10.49238, 45.817792], [10.49238, 47.808381], [5.955894, 47.808381]'

In [511]: lst = eval ("[%s]" % txt)

In [512]: [str(x) for x in lst]
Out[512]:
['[5.955894, 45.817792]',
 '[10.49238, 45.817792]',
 '[10.49238, 47.808381]',
 '[5.955894, 47.808381]']
```