# Python: Split string by pattern

Tags: python, regex, string, split

My question is a variation to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814186/python-splitting-by-certain-pattern). I can't seem to figure this one out.

```
given = "{abc, xyz}, 123, {def, lmn, ijk}, {uvw}, opq"
expected = ["{abc, xyz}", "123", "{def, lmn, ijk}", "{uvw}", "opq"]
```

As in the above example, an item in the `expected` could be a `{..., ...}` or just another `string`.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If the curly braces can be nested, you cannot split it using regular-expressions (at least not in its "pure" form), because it is not a context-free grammer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following regexp fit the job. Howevever you don't have to have nested curly bracket (nested curly bracket can't be parsed using regular expression as far as I know)

```
>>> s= "{abc, xyz}, 123, {def, lmn, ijk}, {uvw}, opq"
>>> re.findall(r",?\s*(\{.*?\}|[^,]+)",s)
['{abc, xyz}', '123', '{def, lmn, ijk}', '{uvw}', 'opq']
```

Comment: May be worth noting why nested curly brackets probably cannot be solved using regular expression...

Comment: As @shx2 noted above, language with nested curly brackets is context-free and requires pushdown automaton to solve. Regular expressions in Python are more or less implementation of regular languages, parsed by finite automata, and thus less powerful.

Comment: I'd change: `\{.*?\}` to `\{[^}]*\}`. It avoids the non-greedy match (which *might* be slower) *and* it matches even if the string contains newlines. Your current solution fails to match things like `{abc,\nxyz}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
given = "{abc,{a:b}, xyz} , 123 , {def, lmn, ijk}, {uvw}, opq"
#expected = ["{abc, xyz}", "123", "{def, lmn, ijk}", "{uvw}", "opq"]
tmp_l = given.split(',')
tmp_l = [i.strip() for i in tmp_l]
result_l = []
element = ''
count = 0
for i in tmp_l:
    if i[0] == '{':
        count += 1
    if i[-1] == '}':
        count -= 1
    element = element + i + ','
    if count == 0:
        element = element[0:-1]
        result_l.append(element)
        element = ''

print str(result_l)
```

this one can handle nested curly bracket, although it seems not so elegant..

Answer (score 0):

Does the following not provide you with what you are looking for?

```
import re
given = "{abc, xyz}, 123, {def, lmn, ijk}, {uvw}, opq"
expected = re.findall(r'(\w+)', given)
```

I ran that in Terminal and got:

```
>>> import re
>>> given = "{abc, xyz}, 123, {def, lmn, ijk}, {uvw}, opq"
>>> expected = re.findall(r'(\w+)', given)
>>> expected
['abc', 'xyz', '123', 'def', 'lmn', 'ijk', 'uvw', 'opq']
```

Comment: That's not it, 'abc' and 'xyz' shouldn't be separate words if they're in the same set of brackets, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below regex to do that. Rest is same as the similar link you provided.

```
given = "{abc, xyz}, 123, {def, lmn, ijk}, {uvw}, opq"
regex = r",?\s*(\{.*?\}|[^,]+)"

print re.findall(regex,given)

OP: ['{abc, xyz}', '123', '{def, lmn, ijk}', '{uvw}', 'opq']
```

Just import the `re` module. and do the same as the link says.
It will match anything inside the curly braces `{` `}` and any string.

Comment: you need re.findall somewhere all that you have is only a tuple

Comment: He has already given the link which explains the rest. Isn't it