# split string python with changing indicator

Tags: python, string, split

lets say I have a string .

```
a = '!!!!!!a1@@@@@@a2&&&&&&a3::::'
```

It naturally splits by: a1,a2 and a3 to

```
['!!!!!!','@@@@@@','&&&&&&','::::']
```

I want to use the `split` function, something like:

```
>>> a.split('a*')
```

The `*` indicates that it doesn't matter what character comes after `a`. Is there an immediate way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Splitting by certain pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814186/python-splitting-by-certain-pattern)

Comment: Is it really any character after `a` or only digit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = '!!!!!!a1@@@@@@a2&&&&&&a3::::'
import re

print(re.split(r'a[0-9]+', s))
```

Answer (score 0):

By using regex, with module `re`, you can try like this:

```
import re
a = re.split(r'a\d','!!!!!!a1@@@@@@a2&&&&&&a3::::')
```

If you want to be more specific in your split keys, try this:

```
a = re.split(r'a1|a2|a3','!!!!!!a1@@@@@@a2&&&&&&a3::::')
```

and make your custom condition, as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

While not as efficient as @Menglong's solution, you could technically do it with just list and string operations, without importing `re`:

```
>>> a = '!!!!!!a1@@@@@@a2&&&&&&a3::::'
>>> s = a.split('a')
>>> s[:1] + [x[1:] for x in s[1:] if x]
['!!!!!!', '@@@@@@', '&&&&&&', '::::']
```

This works because if you split on `'a'`, the first character of every segment after the first will be the `*` character you want to get rid of.

This solution is not preferable, just something I did as an exercise.